# How do I use a escape sequence with a variable?

Tags: python

```
a = "test"
b = "testing"
print a\nb
```

Is there a way I can use an escape sequence with a variable, or is it unnecessary?

Comment: What are you trying to escape here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to print string variables by separating them with the newline character ('\n'), you can do so like this:

```
a = "Hello"
b = "World"
print(a+"\n"+b)
```

[See demo here](http://repl.it/xgl)

Simply executing two separate print statements would also give a similar effect, this is because each print statement automatically inserts a newline character.

```
a = "Hello"
b = "World"
print(a)
print(b)
```

So it isn't necessary to use the newline character to escape a string while printing.

Answer (score 0):

In case you'll have more to print/format in the future a maintainable solution would be,

```
l = [ 'Hello', 'world' ]

# Print with newlines
print('\n'.join(l))

# Print with tabs
print('\t'.join(l))
```

See https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=string%20join#string.join.